how to test if row values in source when taken as columns in target
I have a source table like below,



ID
Column
value




1
apple
10


1
apple
8


1
banana
9


1
banana
12



I have a target table like below,



ID
apple
banana




1
10
9


1
8
12



How do I test/verify this using snowflake

it depends what you are wanting todo, with this knowledge, you could use JOIN to solve this (for this given data) or with WHERE clauses.

Sounds like you need to pivot source first.

with src_data(id, col, val) as (
    select * from values
        (1  ,'apple',   10),
        (1  ,'apple',   8),
        (1  ,'banana',  9),
        (1  ,'banana',  12)
), target_data(id, apple, banana) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 10, 9),
        (1, 8,  12),
        (2, 10, 9),
        (1, 10, 13),
        (1, 7, 12)
)
select t.*
    ,a.val as a_val
    ,b.val as b_val
from target_data as t
left join src_data as a
    on t.id = a.id 
        and a.col = 'apple'
        and t.apple = a.val 
left join src_data as b
    on t.id = b.id 
        and b.col = 'banana'
        and t.banana = b.val                

shows how to join to the data using LEFT JOIN that allow misses:

so now we just change those to INNER JOINS, and only output the t.* values:
select t.*
from target_data as t
join src_data as a
    on t.id = a.id 
        and a.col = 'apple'
        and t.apple = a.val 
join src_data as b
    on t.id = b.id 
        and b.col = 'banana'
        and t.banana = b.val 

and we get filtered results:



ID
APPLE
BANANA




1
10
9


1
8
12



